# object can't get method or property 'getCars'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

i'm working on react-redux intermidiate..but i don't know what's going wrong
on this project

hera i have creacted the searchbar for getting car details..and the file is created as 'search.js'...you can see here..

**search.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { getCars } from '../actions';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

    class Search extends Component{
        constructor(props){
          super(props);

          this.state = {
            keyword:''
          }
        }

      searchCars = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.getCars(this.state.keyword)
      }

      handleChange = (event) => {
          this.setState({
            keyword:event.target.value
          })
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.state);
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div className="main_search">
            <form onSubmit={this.searchCars}>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.keyword} onChange = {this.handleChange} />
            </form>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    // mapStateToProps
    // mapDispatchToProps

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
      return bindActionCreators({getCars}, dispatch)
    }

    export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

and i think error comes from here about **getCars**..which is described below as s 'index.js'...you can see here

**index.js**

```
    const URL_ROOT = 'http://localhost:3004'

    export default function getCars(keywords){
        const request = fetch(`${URL_ROOT}/carsIndex?q=${keywords}`,
          {method:'GET'})
        .then(response => response.json())

        return{
          type:'SEARCH_CARS',
          payload:request
        }
    }
```

and the error looks like this..
[image: error]

and error showing in **bundle.js** file
[image]

so try to fix it and help me...

Comment: check import { getCars } from '../actions'; this path is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Please  change your mapDispatchToProps method as

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=> (
    bindActionCreators(getCars, dispatch) 
)
```

Comment: @mrpanchal please check by  export function getCars(keywords) instead of default export

Comment: @mrpanchal Also your are exporting your action as  import { getCars } from '../actions'; but you have written it on index.js file

Comment: i have puted my files on github..you can chack it and import it on codesandbox...i'm not familiar with it

Comment: search as mrpanchal on github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176958/discussion-between-mrpanchal-and-harikrishnan).